# Question about changing the VLAN assignment for multiple ports

Tags: cisco-commands

So, I'm a server guy, but I'm leading the re-wiring of our patch panel this week. We're going to be moving a bunch of stuff around so we can patch everything in more cleanly, and without the "normal" spaghetti cables.

We're using 3 separate VLAN's here, and I already know which ports are going to need to be on which VLAN's after everything's moved, so I'm set there. And I know that the "interface range GigabitEthernet" command will let me change multiple ports at once. However, everything I was seeing was for doing a single range of ports or a few non-contiguous ports, like this:

```
interface range GigabitEthernet 1/0/4 - 45
interface range GigabitEthernet 1/0/1 , 1/0/47
```

However, can I mix and match? Would something like this work, or can you only have a single range, or just non-contiguous ports?

```
interface range GigabitEthernet 1/0/2 , 1/0/4 - 45 , 2/0/1 - 45 , 3/0/1 - 44 , 4/0/5
```

And is there a limit to the number of port changes I can set with a single command? Because the actual commands I have written down (three long commands, one for each VLAN) are 3-4 times as long as the one above. All with a mixture of ranges and non-contiguous ports.

I just want to have everything as set as possible before tomorrow so I won't be sitting in the office for hours typing in port changes on a Saturday, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a mix/match of them - in fact I just did this today!

For what I did, I used the following:

```
interface range Gig1/0/48, tengig1/1/1 - 4, tengig2/1/1 - 4
```

I believe the limitations of this might vary depending on IOS version though

And according to this Cisco doc, there is no limit on number of ports or types (although I think this also varies):
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/interface/command/ir-cr-book/ir-i1.html#wp3427019564

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot Matt. As long as everything works out (and I didn't make any typos) this will save me hours of typing tomorrow.